# Redmine on Windows 7, rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby, windows-7, redmine, migrate

So I'm trying to install Redmine 2.1.3 on Windows 7 64 bit with WAMP Server 2.2 (c:\wamp\www\redmine) with:

> C:\Users\Deith>gem env
> RubyGems Environment:
>
> - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
> - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371) [i386-mingw32]
> - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
> - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe
> - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby187/bin
> - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
>
>   - ruby
>   - x86-mingw32
> - GEM PATHS:
>
>   - C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
>   - C:/Users/Deith/.gem/ruby/1.8
> - GEM CONFIGURATION:
>
>   - :update_sources => true
>   - :verbose => true
>   - :benchmark => false
>   - :backtrace => false
>   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
> - REMOTE SOURCES:
>
>   - http://rubygems.org/

I'm following this instructions: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall and I'm stuck at the
rake db:migrate. I've created the DB via phpMyAdmin from WAMP Server, and edited the databae.yml file. But when I run

> rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production --trace

I get this:

> ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
>
> ** Invoke environment (first_time)
>
> ** Execute environment

And whole console is frozen, I don't understand what's happening and why it's happening. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you watch the database log to see if there is activity? Also look at task manager to see if something is working. The task does take a long time to run. How long have you waited?

Comment: Ruby is known to be *extremely* slow starting up on Windows.  See https://github.com/rdp/faster_require for one way to speed it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run both commands separately

```
rails_env=production
rake db:migrate
```

also can u show the database config u have done in your config.yml file, you are using sqlite or mysql?

Comment: That's not going to work. (1) because of the case of the environment variable, (2) because environment variables are set differently on windows, i.e. using `SET` and (3) it's useless because they are not two different commands but instead another way to set variables using rake.